# What does my TI-83 or other TI graphing calculators use to numerically approach certain integrals?

Tags: numerical-methods, calculator

I assume that most graphics calculators try to solve things analytically (where possible within reasonable computing time and power). Otherwise do they use numerical approximations for definite integrals and what are they? Gaussian quadrature? Newton-Cotes?

Comment: I don't think they ever do it analytically. I clearly remember an exercise where we were told to use the calculator to calculate $$\int_{-3}^3 e^x-e^{-x}dx$$ as an illustration of the fact that calculators don't do things analytically. The book was made with the Casio $fx$-$9$xxx series or Texas Instruments TI-$8$x series in mind, so I assume it's the same for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TI documentation](https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=93707) states that the `fInt()` function of TI-83 or TI-84 Plus uses the [Gauss-Kronrod method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula).

It seems that the official documentation never discloses the number of points used, but [a user's experiment](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7091862) indicates it is the [15-point formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula#Example).